# 0x unstaking not possible on the site

Tags: 0x

I want to unstake my 0x from the site. But is does not work. Please help. My account 0x26336EA0829cd88307032DB2C8ABaaa05e97e082.

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

can you share a little bit more detail on the issue you're encountering? What wallet/browser are you using?
Also, about 2 days ago there were some problems with a gas oracle API that should be now solved. Can you check again if it works now?
Thanks